# Where can I find lens mounts for small 2 mm diameter lenses?

Tags: lens-mount, lens-adapter, cameraphones, smartphone

I need a lens mount for one of my projects. I have a CCD chip, a single lens (2 mm diameter), and I know the mechanical position and tolerances. I would like to find a lens mount for that lens or see whether I can take advantage of some existing small lens mounts, like the Raspbery Pi camera module lens mount.  Here are my questions:

What type of lens mount is used on [the Raspbery Pi camera module](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/camera-module-v2/)? It seems that the [Infenion Tof camera](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/sensor/3d-image-sensor-real3/) uses the same lens mount.

Which company produces these lens mounts and from which vendor can one  buy these small or similar lens mounts (like for mobile phones or other compact devices) that attach to a PCB?

The smallest lens mounts I found was an S Mount M12x0.5 type.
For test purposes I bought a couple of female S type lens holder for webcams and then screwed in some of my small S Type lenses. Mechanical play here was too big. I had expected a very tight fit since these are opto-mechanical components, but the lens could still move even when almost fully screwed in.

Comment: Edmund optics is a go-to for these sorts of endeavors

Answer (score 1):

I have checked Edmund Optics, and they do *not* offer mounts for such small lenses. Also checked Thorlabs, Newport, laser2000, Qioptiq, and they also don't have such mounts off the shelf. There is a possibility to make a custom S Mount.

Wikipedia Lens mount page states that for small camera modules there are Mounts from M12x0.5 all the way down to M4.2x0.2 (1/7" sensors). For example, [1/7" 2.0mm F2.8 Megapixel M4.2x0.2 mount](http://www.megapixellenses.com/sale-8078387-1-7-2-0mm-f2-8-megapixel-m4-2x0-2-mount-non-distortion-lens-plastic-2mm-mobile-lens.html), but minimum order is 100pcs.